# What is wrong with my SQL Query for the Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

Here is what I am supposed to do. Assume that the tables are created, and all the columns are correctly named

"Using stored procedures and cursors, display the location (including street, zip code, city and country) of the managers with job id of either IT_PROG or SA_MAN and with salary greater than 3000".

Here is the code I have written so far but the sql statement for the cursor doesn't seem to want to work. For the DEPARTMENTS Table the FK's are MANAGER_ID and LOCATION_ID, for the EMPLOYEES Table the FK is JOB_ID and the LOCATIONS table has no FK. All the primary keys are set

Here is the code:

```
create or replace procedure mgtLocation
is
    cursor getLoc is
        select LOCATIONS.STREET_ADDRESS, LOCATIONS.POSTAL_CODE, LOCATIONS.CITY, 
               LOCATIONS.COUNTRY, LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_ID, LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_ID
          from LOCATIONS 
    inner join DEPARTMENTS on DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID = EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID
    inner join LOCATIONS on LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID = DEPARTMENTS.LOCATION_ID
         where EMPLOYEES.Job_ID in (select Job_ID from EMPLOYEES where Job_ID = 'IT_PROG' or Job_ID = 'SA_MAN' and SALARY > 3000); 
    EmpLoc getLoc%rowtype;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('=================');
    open getLoc;
    loop
        fetch getLoc into EmpLoc;
        EXIT WHEN getLoc%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line('Street: ' || EmpLoc.STREET_ADDRESS ||
            ' Zip Code: ' || EmpLoc.POSTAL_CODE ||
            ' City: ' || EmpLoc.CITY ||
            ' Country: ' || EmpLoc.COUNTRY);
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('=================');
    close getLoc;
end;
/
execute mgtLocation;
```

I get an error for the inner joins and I cannot seem to figure out how to fix them in order for this to work.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please check, in your query you've not specified  table `employees` in the from clause but are referring to it in joins

Comment: What error do you get? Got a ORA-xxxxx for us?

Comment: Looks like a simple bug: `from LOCATIONS` should be `from EMPLOYEES`,

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
cursor getLoc is
    select LOCATIONS.STREET_ADDRESS, 
          LOCATIONS.POSTAL_CODE, LOCATIONS.CITY, 
          LOCATIONS.COUNTRY, LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_ID, 
          LOCATIONS.LOCATIONS_ID
    from LOCATIONS 
    inner join DEPARTMENTS  on   
          DEPARTMENTS.LOCATION_ID = LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID  
    inner join EMPLOYEES on 
          EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID = 
          DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID
    where (EMPLOYEES.Job_ID = 'IT_PROG' or 
          EMPLOYEES.Job_ID = 'SA_MAN') 
    and SALARY > 3000;
```